# Not able to create a web service configuration in Service Manger client 9.80 with newly created table

Tags: opentext, microfocus, hp-service-manager

While creating a new web service with my newly created table , i am not able to see the new table in list.

```
416(  8068) 03/15/2024 08:15:51.132  RTE D sql diff 0.000  total 56.189  call#:12549 --> _prepare:SELECT * FROM UMBTTEVENTSM1
   416(  8068) 03/15/2024 08:15:51.133  RTE D sql diff 0.000  total 56.189  call#:12550 --> sqociInit - *`**EXECUTE DESCRIBE_ONLY:SELECT * FROM UMBTTEVENTSM1
   416(  8068) 03/15/2024 08:15:51.133  RTE E Error: SQL code=942 message=ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
   416(  8068) 03/15/2024 08:15:51.134  RTE E API=OCIStmtExecute [in sqociInit], Statement=SELECT * FROM UMBTTEVENTSM1**`*
   416(  8068) 03/15/2024 08:15:51.135  RTE D sql diff 0.000  total 56.189  call#:12551 --> _errorStatement:ROLLBACK
   416(  8068) 03/15/2024 08:15:51.135  RTE D (0x6C1B5A80) InitHash called for file dbdict with 54 fields
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO1Qc.png)

I am excepting to display my newly created table in the list.